Is a smooth submersion with closed fibers from a closed $3$-manifold to a non-Hausdorff $1$-manifold almost a fiber bundle over $S^1$?
Suppose $M$ is a connected and closed smooth $3$-manifold, $S$ is a $1$-dimensional locally Euclidean space with a given smooth structure, and $F : M \to S$ is a surjective smooth submersion with closed fibers. Note that $S$ may not be Hausdorff, but is necessarily second countable, compact, and connected. The following may be irrelevant, but it appears in the concrete cases I am studying: Assume that the Hausdorff quotient of $S$ has discrete fibers, and all but finitely many have size $1$.
This is similar to the situation in which Ehresmann's Lemma applies, so I have the hope that $F$ more or less lifts to the circle. Is there a finite cover $\pi_M :\widehat{M} \to M$, a smooth submersion $\widehat{F} : \widehat{M} \to S^1$, and a local diffeomorphism $\sigma : S^1 \to S$, such that $F \circ \pi_M = \sigma \circ \widehat{F}$?
I am not sure if the following is relevant. It applies some of the time, but apparently not always. If there is a quotient of $S$ which is a circle and which has a smooth structure so that the quotient map is a smooth submersion, then composing $F$ with this quotient map gives a proper smooth submersion to a circle. E.g., if $S$ has a single double point, the Hausdorff quotient behaves this way.
I only just started reading some books on foliation theory with greater attention, so this question may simply be the result of a lack of awareness of basic examples. So one optimistic objective in posting this is just to learn some new examples.
Another thought is, since not all closed $3$-manifolds $N$ are finitely covered by surface bundles,
a counterexample to this question can be found by constructing a submersion from one such $N$ to some $S$. The Wikipedia page on the Virtually fibered conjecture says Seifert manifolds with non-zero orbifold Euler characteristic base manifolds do not have finite covers which are surface bundles. I'm not sure how to use that at the moment, however.

You mean the conditon with the cover, right? $F$ is a map $M\rightarrow S$, while $\sigma\circ\widehat{F}$ is a map $\widehat{M}\rightarrow S$.

An update for anybody who may be interested in this. I was informed that the induced foliation on $M$ is a fiber bundle over an orbifold leaf space … The key points, I think, are Theorems 4.1 - 4.3 of Epstein’s paper Foliations with all Leaves Compact, and an argument from Reebs’s thesis showing bounded leaf volume for codimension one foliations with compact leaves in compact manifolds. The first few paragraphs of the Edwards-Millett-Sullivan paper suggest this. I’m trying to learn enough of the basics to write an answer. I haven’t been able to locate Reebs’s thesis, unfortunately.

Yes.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the smooth foliation on $M$ induced by $F$, which has leaves equal to the connected components of the pre-images of $F$. This exists because $F$ is assumed to be a smooth submersion; note that $S$ is Hausdorff on small enough neighborhoods, so you can view this as using the standard smooth manifold concept on small enough neighborhoods if you desire. The leaves are compact properly embedded submanifolds because they are connected components of closed sets in a compact manifold, by assumption. They are codimension $1$ because $S$ is $1$-dimensional.
The discussion at the beginning of [Candel-Conlon, Chapter 3.5 Orientation Covers] explains the existence of transversely orientable double covers with analogy to orientable double covers: A connected manifold with a foliation, such as $M$, has a $2$-sheet cover $\widetilde{\pi}_M : \widetilde{M} \to M$ such that $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}} := (\widetilde{\pi}_M)^\ast \mathcal{F}$ is transversely orientable. And, $\widetilde{M}$ is disconnected if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is already transversely orientable.
(See [Candel-Conlon, Definition 1.2.14] for the definition of a transversely orientable foliation. This involves regular foliated atlas (Definition 1.2.11) and holonomy cocycle of a regular foliated atlas (Definition 1.2.12). The pull-back foliation construction is explained in [Candel-Conlon, Theorem 3.2.2], and generalizes the construction of a foliation with leaves equal to the connected components of the pre-images of a submersion. Also see [Candel-Conlon, Definition 2.3.6] for the definition of the holonomy group of a leaf, as this concept appears later in this post.)
So now we let $\widehat{M}$ equal $M$ if $M$ is transversely orientable already, or $\widetilde{M}$ otherwise. We let $\pi_M$ denote the covering map $\widehat{M} \to M$, which is either $1$ or $2$-sheeted, and let $\widehat{\mathcal{F}} := (\pi_M)^\ast \mathcal{F}$. Note that the leaves of $\widehat{\mathcal{F}}$ are also compact properly embedded submanifolds of codimension $1$, and $\widehat{M}$ is a compact manifold.
Now I quote the theorem on global Reeb stability from Candel and Conlon's text, and I duplicate some of the text from my other answer. The validity of this answer is contingent on the bold text I've added being correct. I want to add that this seems to be common knowledge by those with experience in foliation theory.

[Candel-Conlon, Theorem 6.1.5]: Let $(M, \mathcal{F})$ be a compact, connected, transversely orientable, foliated manifold of codimension one. If there is a compact leaf $L$ having finite fundamental group (GS: there is apparently no harm at all in improving this assumption to the assumption that the compact leaf $L$ has finite holonomy group), then every leaf is homeomorphic to $L$ and $M$ is homeomorphic either to $L \times [0, 1]$, foliated as a product, or to the total space of a fiber bundle $p : M \to S^1$ having the leaves of $\mathcal{F}$ as fibers.

[Candel-Conlon Theorem 2.3.12] states that for arbitrary foliated manifolds, leaves having trivial holonomy are generic (which here means their union contains a countable intersection of open, dense subsets, so is in particular non-empty). Since $\widehat{M}$ is a manifold without boundary, we conclude from these facts that the map $\widehat{F} : \widehat{M} \to \widehat{M} / \widehat{\mathcal{F}} \approx S^1$ is a fiber bundle. Since $F \circ \pi_M$ is constant on the fibers of $\widehat{F}$, it follows that there exists a continuous map $\sigma : S^1 \to S$ such that $F \circ \pi_M = \sigma \circ \widehat{F}$. Since $\widehat{F}$ has smooth local sections, it follows that $\sigma$ is a smooth submersion, hence must be a local diffeomorphism since $\mathrm{dim}(S) = \mathrm{dim}(S^1)$.
Candel, Alberto; Conlon, Lawrence, Foliations I, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 23. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xiv, 402 p. (2000). ZBL0936.57001.

Vogt writes in Existence of foliations of Euclidean spaces with all leaves compact, "It is an immediate consequence of the definition of holonomy that every transversally orientable foliation of codimension 1 with all leaves compact is given by the fibres of a fibre bundle over a 1-manifold."
For manifolds without boundary $M$, the assumption that $M$ is compact can be dropped from [Candel-Conlon, Theorem 6.1.5] and the conclusion weakened to '$M$ fibers over a (Hausdorff) 1-manifold', and the same arguments apply.
